# If I develop a chat server using Twisted, where can I deploy it?

Tags: deployment, twisted

1. If I develop a chat server using Twisted, where can I deploy it?
   Suppose I develop a web application. I can deploy it on any commercial server which allows hosting of web applications.
2. But if I devlop a comet using twisted, where can I deploy it?
3. What kind of server do I need for this?

In short I want to know where can I host my comet server.
I want to deploy a application similar to http://omegle.com/.
This site also used Twisted.

Comment: We need more details than that.

Comment: suppose i develop a webapplicati i can deploy it on any commertial server which allows hosting of web application. But if i devlop a comet using twiste dwhere can i deply it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy Twisted on any hosting provider who gives you a shell prompt and doesn't limit your long-running processes.