# Creating and deploying a python chat application using Twisted

Tags: python, hosting, chat, twisted

I have created a **chat server application** using the Twisted framework. I am running it on my local machine and now I want to go global. The application is similar to omegle.com.

How can I develop on a third party commercial server so that it runs continuously?
Do I need to get a dedicated server for it?

Comment: possible duplicate (as mentioned in an answer below):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956869/if-i-develop-a-chat-server-using-twisted-where-can-i-deploy-it

Answer (score 3):

As per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956869/if-i-develop-a-chat-server-using-twisted-where-can-i-deploy-it),

> You can deploy Twisted on any hosting
> provider who gives you a shell prompt
> and doesn't limit your long-running
> processes.

The hosting server need not be dedicated, in other words, as long as those conditions are met (and of course as long as you have enough quota of RAM, disk, bandwidth, etc, for your purposes).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Python friendly hosts](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonHosting) to get an idea of what is available and what it will cost you. Typically, you could get away with a shared hosting package as long as you have a shell. However, if your program begins serving tons of clients, you might need to move it to a dedicated host.